# Is a Möbius transformation that PRESERVES UNIT DISC uniquely determined by three distinct points and their images?

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

If I have given four different points in a disc : $a,b,c,d$
Does always exist a Möbius transformation $w$ which PRESERVES UNIT DISC , so that $w(a)=c$ and $w(b)=d$? If yes, is it unique?

If given 6 points: $a,b,c,d,e,f$, then I look for a transformation(which preserves unit disc) that maps: $w(a)=d , w(b)=e , w(c)=f$. If this transformation (also) exists, is it unique?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the first question: no, $w$ need not exist, although when it does exist it is unique. The reason is that the [Poincare distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model#Metric_and_curvature) $d(x,y)$ between two points $x$ and $y$ in the unit disc is invariant under all Möbius transformations, so a necessary condition for the existence of $w$ is that $d(a,b)=d(c,d)$. That equation is also a sufficient condition for the existence of $w$, and moreover if $w$ exists then it is unique.

This pretty obviously addresses your second question as well: no, $w$ need not exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering! Do you have any link/book/site or something you could send me so I can read a little bit more about this,where this is explained in some more details?Thank you in advance!

Comment: And what would exactly be the 'condition of existence' in the second case?

Comment: For the second case, roughly speaking the SSS theorem holds: an isometry exists taking $\triangle abc$ to $\triangle def$ if and only if corresponding distances are equal. However, not every isometry is a Möbius transformation: that happens if and only the isometry preserves orientation, if and only if the two triangles are **not** mirror images of each other.

Comment: If I have given that those 6 points are actually on the disk boundary (unit circle) , will those transformation ALWAYS exist and how can I prove it?Thank you

Comment: That's an interesting question, and it might make a good question for a new post. But it's not a good use for this site to put a new question in a comment to an answer to an old question, where no-one will see the new question except you and me.

Comment: I've just made a new question for given 8 points on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3673283/for-given-eight8-points-a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h-on-unit-circle-does-always-a-m%c3%b6bi?noredirect=1#comment7548385_3673283 .I hope someone will see :)