# How to prove uniqueness?

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-geometry, mobius-transformation

For the question asked in [Is a Möbius transformation that PRESERVES UNIT DISC uniquely determined by three distinct points and their images?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3671875/is-a-m%c3%b6bius-transformation-that-preserves-unit-disc-uniquely-determined-by-three/3671909#3671909) , how can I prove the UNIQUENESS of those transformations (when they exist)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The idea is always the same: If $T$ and $S$ are two such transformations then $T^{-1}\circ S$ is a Möbius transformation which preserves the unit disk *and* has two fixed points. Now have a look at the Schwarz(-Pick) Lemma.

Comment: I thought that I can use that only in second case(in the first question asked-that link) when I have given 6 points: 3 distinct points and their images.But I'm not sure what can I do for the first case when I have given only 4 points... Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have an automorphism of the unit disk which maps $0$ and one other point onto itself then it is the identity mapping. Can you prove that? Can you apply that to your question?

Comment: I know to prove that every Möbius transformation that preserves unit disc has exactly two fixed points.How can I use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Möbius transformation which preserves the unit disk is uniquely determined by the images of two distinct points, i.e. if $T, S$ are automorphisms of the unit disk with $T(z_j) = S(z_j)$ for $z_1 \ne z_2$ then $T = S$.

For a proof consider $\phi = T^{-1} \circ S$. $\phi$ is an automorphism of the unit disk with two fixed points $z_1, z_2$ inside the unit disk. Now there are two possible ways to continue:

- Show that the “mirror points” $1/\,\overline{z_k}$ are also fixed points of $\phi$ and conclude that $\phi$ is the identity.
- Or consider $g = f \circ \phi \circ f^{-1}$ where $f$ is an automorphism of the unit disk with $f(z_1) = 0$. Then $g$ has the two fixed points $0$ and $f(z_2)$. Use the Schwarz Lemma to conclude that $g$ is the identity.

Comment: If I have given that those 6 points are actually on the disk boundary (unit circle) , will those transformation ALWAYS exist and how can I prove it? Thank you!